# Binding variable to a textblock in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In XAML, i have a textblock

```
<TextBlock x:Name="block" Text="{Binding b1}"/>
```

and in c# i created a property

```
public int _b1;
public int b1
    {
        get { return _b1; }
        set
        {
            _b1 = value;
        }
    }

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    block.DataContext = this;
}
```

this worked fine, textblock show the _b1. But when i add a button to chage the _b1 variable

```
private void bt_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _b1 = 4; 
    }
```

the textblock didn't update ?????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to dotNet's answer (which is the correct answer), use a baseclass where you implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you want to avoid redundand code: (this is one example, there are other ways to implement this)

```
  public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value)) { return false; }

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
class MyClass: BindableBase
{
        private int _b1;
        public int B1
        {
            get { return _b1; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _b1, value); }
        }
}
```

Comment: ok, now i can change b1 to change to textblock, but changing _b1 still doesn't update the textblock :(

Comment: If you look at the code that notifies the changes you can see its not how it works. Set B1 = 4; The private field- called a backing field stores the old value so we have something to check against, the property is what what the control is atually bound to and where the magic should happen :)

Answer (score 3):

For UI to update automatically upon property value change, your property needs to either be a `DependencyProperty` or your class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

For creating a DependencyProperty, you could use Visual Studio's `propdp` snippet (type **propdp** inside your class and press Tab) and fill in respective values. If you want to go `INotifyPropertyChanged` path, you'll need to write the following code in the setter of your property (AFTER setting the value of `_b1`):

```
if(PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("b1"));
```